# Android format date using X country translation

Tags: android, locale

For date parsing, I'm using `SimpleDateFormat`.
I know that it's possible to pass `Locale` object to translate month names.

I tried to use the Estonian language: `Locale("ee", "Estonia")`, but it did not work.
Am I using the wrong language code or Estonian language is not supported thus I've to use a different approach?

Comment: Isn't Estonia `et_EE`? ([Source](https://saimana.com/list-of-country-locale-code/)). I would also consider *not* using SimpleDateFormat, and instead use Java.Time package (if you support API 26+). [Formatting in Java.time is much easier and performant](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/java8-datetimeformatter-example/), as you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use Estonian by using:

```
Locale("et", "ee")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the correct Locale for any country from [Translations Editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor#open) in Android studio.

For Estonian country, Locale should be `Locale("et", "ee")`

[image]